# How to convert a huge scientific notation number to float or double?

Tags: php

I a string “2.1360000028538e+22“, and I want to put it in decimal form. It should be 21,360.000028537997.

How can I convert this in PHP? I believe the scientific notation is too big, but is there any workarounds or libraries I can use to do this?

Comment: What is your code? All we have here is a string

Answer (score 0):

Use number_format()

`$a= 2.1360000028538e+22;
print number_format($a,2);`

Comment: This isn't conversion, it's just output. OP stated they want conversion, and we'd need to know their code for that really. Perhaps they want to do calculations with it?